# Log-linear model, Poisson regression, categorical variable with 100 levels

Tags: r, regression, poisson

I want to compare the incidence rate(asum) of 100 different cities(cityID) to see if there are significant differences among them. Given that the incidence rate is following Poisson, so it is a log-linear model.

```
m0=glm(asum~cityID, family=poisson, data=suit)
summary(m0)
```

However, the result looks so clumsy and stupid. Have I done anything wrong? Or is there any better way to analyse the data for my purpose?

```
Call:
glm(formula = asum ~ cityID, family = poisson, data = suit)

Deviance Residuals: 
  [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [25]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [49]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [73]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [97]  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.63759    0.16222  22.424  < 2e-16 ***
cityID2      1.68542    0.17662   9.543  < 2e-16 ***
cityID3      1.79614    0.17516  10.254  < 2e-16 ***
cityID4      2.17355    0.17120  12.696  < 2e-16 ***
cityID5      1.02585    0.18908   5.426 5.78e-08 ***
cityID6      2.20306    0.17095  12.887  < 2e-16 ***
:
:
:
cityID90     0.92676    0.19166   4.836 1.33e-06 ***
cityID91     1.28239    0.18334   6.994 2.66e-12 ***
cityID92     2.40267    0.16940  14.183  < 2e-16 ***
cityID93     1.39937    0.18113   7.726 1.11e-14 ***
cityID94    -1.23969    0.34238  -3.621 0.000294 ***
cityID95     0.59652    0.20201   2.953 0.003148 ** 
cityID96    -2.25129    0.52566  -4.283 1.85e-05 ***
cityID97     1.86367    0.17435  10.689  < 2e-16 ***
cityID98     1.82625    0.17479  10.448  < 2e-16 ***
cityID99     1.96453    0.17322  11.341  < 2e-16 ***
cityID100    0.93712    0.19138   4.897 9.74e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.0608e+04  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.8200e-14  on  0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 804.18

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

Comment: What's the problem? You solved a problem in100 unknowns with 100 estimated free parameters.  So your model is "saturated" and you have perfect predictions and your residual deviance is effectively 0. This is not really appropriate for SO. Would have been a better fit for stats.stackexchange.com (as also would have been the question you deleted 2 hours ago.)

Comment: Are you sure regression is the best approach when the predictor variable is discrete?

Comment: @AdamQuek As I want to have some numerical output besides the graphical approach that I have already done, log-linear model is the best that I can think of. Could you suggest some other appropriate methods?

Comment: How bout ANOVA and post-hoc test (e.g. Tukey HSD)? Doesn't make sense to regress across the different cities. Not unless cityID1 is smaller than cityID2 and so on, or vice versa...

Comment: @AdamQuek But for ANOVA, we still need to go for glm() to build up models as input for ANOVA to compare.

Comment: I was thinking of using an example data to illustrate how to go about analysing the data, and then realised that you do have any variance per cityID (i.e. one value one city). This mean that any linear model would probably not be able to provide any statistically meaning.